# Why recursive grid binding causes stack overflow in .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

This code is binding gridview recursively, which is causing a stack overflow issue with the error: "The thread used up its stack".

```c#
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    if (NavHandler.InSecurityManager) return;

    //Profile the start and stop of the linq call

    LinqDS.Selecting += delegate { StepSelecting = MiniProfiler.Current.Step("Grid: " + ID + " - Select"); };

    LinqDS.Selected += delegate { if (StepSelecting != null) StepSelecting.Dispose(); };

    //...and the databind
    DBG.DataBinding += delegate { StepDatabind = MiniProfiler.Current.Step("Grid: " + ID + " - Databind"); };

    DBG.DataBound += delegate { if (StepDatabind != null) StepDatabind.Dispose(); };
}

protected void DBG_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PageControls.Visible = DBG.PageCount > 1;

    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        var key = GridKey;

        var page = Session[key] != null ? (int)Session[key] : 0;

        SetPage(page);
    }
}

private void SetPage(int page)
{
    DBG.PageIndex = page;

    Session[GridKey] = page;
}
```

Please find below bind related code

```
  public event EventHandler DataBound
        {
            add { DBG.DataBound += value; }

            remove { DBG.DataBound -= value; }
        }
```

Comment: Where are you actually databinding?

Comment: public event EventHandler DataBound
        {
            add { DBG.DataBound += value; }
            remove { DBG.DataBound -= value; }
        }

Answer (score 0):

SetPage() causes the binding method to fire which fires SetPage() and so on.

Comment: How SetPage Method calling binding method?